# Understanding Symfony role permissions and templating

Tags: php, security, twig, roles, symfony-2.7

I've inherited a Symfony 2.7.5 project that extensively uses groups through the default Symfony methods.

I've got the need to create a few extra roles now and restrict various bits and pieces.

After going through the Symfony 2 manual and various resources (including various answers here), it looks so simple - it basically says that since Symfony 2, the command should be:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_MY_NEW_ROLE') %}
code here 
{% endif %}
```

but I just couldn't get this working. After messing around for ages, I came up with the following:

```
{% set hasMyRole = is_granted('ROLE_MY_NEW_ROLE', moduleManager.module) %}
{% if hasMyRole %}
Stuff my role here...
{% endif %}
```

which does work.

This seems rather nasty and it was brute force and testing that got me here. I really don't think I have this right and was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction, or, should I stick with what I have/has this project got a bad implementation of roles?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache and logging out/in again after messing with the roles? Just going to weed out the obvious as I haven't seen that hack used before

Comment: Hi @JimL - yep unfortunately. I'm no expert at Symfony in the slightest, but, I've tried the "obvious" things. I got it working as I wrote above, I just feel like I've done it in an overly complicated way when the documentation shows that it should be much simpler.

Comment: This may sound funny, but I would try making your Role all capital, every Symfony example available uses all caps for roles. I am on a newer version of Symfony, but your original code is exactly what I use, I did look at the version 2.7 docs (https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/security.html) but didn't see anything that would help.

Comment: @MEmerson updated question, no change :( and sorry, I think I did use capitals in the real code.